# Redis failover cluster convert-to-slave

Tags: redis

After sentinel failover. My slave prometed as a new master. But my old master couldn't convert as a slave. Sentinel's log is below getting forever :)

26378:X 23 May 17:55:00.429 * +convert-to-slave slave 10.0.22.43:6379 10.0.22.43 6379 @ master01 10.0.22.44 6379

I tested this redis v3.2.0 and v3.0.7

same error. I am missing something.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. did you find any solution to this ?

Comment: This might be following bug https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3285

Comment: @Viraj nope.I am still thinking what am i missed..i think it is not same case what am i faced on your link